# Calling init() inside doget() method of servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

Please advise what would happen If I call an `init()` method inside the `doget()` method of a servlet.  Will it throw an exception?  What impact would it have on the servlet life cycle?

Please advise.

Comment: Never ever do this. It makes the server cross over to the dark side and fry the machine that's running the browser and then it destroys itself. Depending on where your server and the browser sending the fateful get request are located, it may also cause disruptions in the  transatlantic submarine communications cable.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the code inside of your `init()` method will execute.

There is nothing special about the `init` method, except that the container will call it before your servlet is put into service. You can call it whenever you'd like. If your `init` method changes the values of any shared data, then you may experience odd issues.

I can't imagine why anyone would have to call `init` from within their `doGet` method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could avoid asking this question if you tried to invoke your `init()` method from the `doGet()` and see what happens.

Anyway, Servlet Spec 2.3 says:

> Initialization is provided so that a servlet can read persistent
>   configuration data, initialize costly resources (such as JDBC™ API
>   based connections), and perform other one-time activities.

So, you should wonder how many of those *one-time activities* are in your current `init()` method. Invoking that method isn't different than invoking a different one. I'm thinking in a scenario in which your `init()` method the only thing that it does is initialize owned attributes from the `ServetConfig`'s init parameters; in that case nothing wrong will happen.

But if your `init()` method performs any tasks that may change the internal state of the servlet then you have a chance to face a strange behaviour.

If you are doing any task in your `init()` method that you may need to use in your `doGet()`, then move them to a private internal method.

Answer (score 0):

**If you didn't implemented init() method, quite much nothing will happen**. Reason is that also inherited implementation is empty. Your servlet likely extends HttpServlet, which inherits following implementation from GenericServlet:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    // NOOP by default
}
```

**If you have your own implementation, then code in your implementation is executed**. Does it throw exception - that depends about what you coded in.

If you call init which takes ServletConfig as argument, then original ServletConfig gets replaced and `init()` is called. I cannot see reason why you would want to call `init` or `init(ServletConfig)` methods. Methods is for you to override when needed, and to be called by servlet container.